# What do you do if there is no Levi or Bechor to wash the Kohain's hands?

Tags: kohen-priest, netilat-yadayim-washing, birchas-kohanim, levites-leviyim

What do you do by Duchaning when there is no Levi or Bechor to wash the Kohain's hands?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe the Cohen washes his own.  If I recall correctly, the Gemara just talks about how Cohanim wash.  Having someone else do it is the Zohar.

Comment: Does the Cohen wash himself or does another Cohen wash him?

Comment: I think he washes his own.

Comment: Source........?

Comment: Sources:
- [Qitzur Shulhhan Arukh, Orahh Hayim 128:24](http://www.ateret4u.com/online/f_01355_part_7.html#סימןBקכחB-BהלכותBנשיאתBכפים-כד)
- [Mishnah Berurah 128:6, Comment 22](http://www.mishnaberurayomi.org/pdf_pages/Chelek_2/0003_Siman_128_Seif_4b-6a.pdf)

Answer (score 14):

If there is no levi, a bechor (firstborn) should do so. If there aren’t any bechorim, then the kohein should wash his own hands ([M.B. 128 sk. 22](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14164&pgnum=4)).